# Connect Multiple GCloud SQL DBs OR GCloud and local DB in one spring application

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I have come across a situation where in I need to connect a local MySQL DB and a GCloud SQL DB in one spring application.
If it were 2 local DBs, then we can use 2 spring configurations set up manually on the application and things would work fine, below is an example of such config.

```
public class DBConfig {
@Primary
@Bean(name="primDatasource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.admissions.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource(){
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name="primEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("primDatasource") DataSource dataSource
)
{
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .properties(properties)
            .packages("com.kishore.multidb.outliers")
            .persistenceUnit("outl")
            .build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name="transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("primEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory
)
{
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
}
```

However, the same did not work for my cloud sql configurations, below is the application.yml

```
spring:
cloud-config:
cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name: "cloud-sql-project-283416:us-central1:sql-test-one"
cloud.gcp.sql.database-name: "sql_db_one"
```

And below is a sample gcloud config file :

```html
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "cloudEntityManagerFactory"
)
public class CloudSQLConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="cloudDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.cloud-config")
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="cloudEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("cloudDatasource") DataSource dataSource
    )
    {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .properties(properties)
                .packages("com.kishore.multidb.outliers")
                .persistenceUnit("cloud-outl")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="cloudTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("cloudEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory
    )
    {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

These are the dependencies that I have added for gcloud sql.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am not sure if I am doing this the right way. There maybe a different way for configuring a cloud sql db manually in spring.

Please help !!!